Oracle which gives a polynomial equivalent to Diffie-Hellman?
If we have an oracle which returns square in the exponent (that is, given $g^X\bmod p$ returns $g^{X^2}\bmod p$), we can solve Diffie-Hellman.
Suppose it returns $P(X)$ for a polynomial $P(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$ (that is, given $g^X\bmod p$ returns $g^{P(X)}\bmod p$), can we solve Diffie-Hellman?


Suppose it returns $P(X)$ for a polynomial $P(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$ (that is, given $g^X\bmod p$ returns $g^{P(X)}\bmod p$), can we solve Diffie-Hellman?

It turns out that the answer is "Yes" (with the assumptions that $P$ is known, the degree of $P$ is at least 2 and not ridiculously large, and the most significant term of $P$ does not have a large gcd with $p-1$ [1]).
First thing to look at is: if we had a $P$ with degree exactly two, can we solve it?
In that case, we have $P(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$.  Now, if we try the exact same strategy that works with the $P(x) = x^2$ case, we ask our Oracle for $g^{P(x)}, g^{P(y)}, g^{P(x+y)}$, and compute $g^{P(x+y)} / (g^{P(x)} \cdot g^{P(y)})$.  Written out, this is [2]:
$$g^{ax^2 + 2axy + ay^2 + bx + by + c - (ax^2 + bx + c) - (ay^2 + by + c)}$$
or (after we cancel terms) $g^{2axy} / g^c$
$c$ is a known constant (so we can remove the $g^c$ term).
Then, as long as $2a$ does not have a large gcd with $p-1$, we can compute $g^{xy}$ from $g^{2axy}$, thus solving the CDH problem.

Now, let us consider the case that the degree of $P$ is greater than two.
We take advantage of the fact that $Q(x) = P(x+1) - P(x)$ is a polynomial degree one less than $P$.  That is, if $P(x) = ax^n + bx^{n-1} + ...$, then $P(x+1) - P(x) = nax^{n-1} + ...$.
We can use this to whittle down the degree of $P$ until it is degree two (with the assumption we made that the degree wasn't ridiculously large), thus turning the problem into the above already solved case.
Then, we can use the oracle to compute $g^{P'(x)}$, where $P'$ is the resulting polynomial of degree two

[1]: If $p$ is a strong prime, then it is sufficient that the most signficant term of $P$ not be a multiple of $q = (p-1)/2$
[2]: And this sort of equation is why I prefer additive notation

Interesting.....
